# Vue computed property not updating

Tags: vue.js

I have an empty object data property

```
data() {
  return {
    chosen: {},
  }
}
```

Then I have a computed property the results of which are related with chosen property.

```
myComputed() {
  let result = 0
  Object.entries(this.chosen).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    result = result + value
  })
  return result
```

}

Then I have a method that actually changes the chosen property

```
setChosen(someValue) {
  this.chosen['key'] = someValue
}
```

So when I call setChosen and adding a new value the myComputed is not executed and not updating my view value.

Comment: you are trying to access to your object attribute as array attribute within your computed method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's caused by your computed method not detecting the change, read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

**Try the folowing:**

```
setChosen(someValue) {
    // IF no key is parsed
    this.$set(this.chosen, 'key', someValue)

    // IF key is parsed
    // this.$set(this.chosen, key, someValue)

}
```

Obviously if someValue is only the value, you need to wrap the 'key' in quotes to directly name it: key. If your function is parsed a second value as a string, just use that directly.

Reactively set the new value